# How to stream data to a csv file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, download, stream

I want to stream GPS data and some additional data into 
a CSV file on the client browser.

I get the gps data through navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate).

The other data is collected with:

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "data.html", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
   if (txtFile.readyState === 4) 
   {  
       if (txtFile.status === 200) 
       {  
          allText = txtFile.responseText;
          lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
          if ( typeof(lines[1]) !== 'undefined' ) { VALUE_A = lines[1]; }
       }
   }
}
```

How can I start a file download and write the data continuously to a file on the client with javascript or HTML?

How can I implement a stop button on the web page in order to let the user stop the download?

Comment: You will need to use a server such as node.js It should be possible to stream the data to a file, but it will be likely that the csv won't be visible until after they have clicked the stop button, where the download is finalized and can then be viewed by the client.

Comment: Alternatively, continuously request the data client side, save that into the page e.g. into a html element textContent, and then have a download button. This won't stream it to their hard drive filesystem as it will still be sandboxed in the browser, until they click download and download it.

Comment: I don't think that it will work with textContent. If the data is recorded for several hours, it probably gets to big.  Are there examples for a node.js streaming download?

Comment: I have the problem solved by using [StreamSaver.js](https://jimmywarting.github.io/StreamSaver.js).